# {\phantom{X}} sometimes higher than X

Tags: math-mode, height

Why is `{\vphantom{X}}^2` (`%8`) higher than any of the other options? In particular, why is it higher than `%5`, `%6`, and `%7`. The behavior is normal if I use a lower-case character instead of the X.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
  \fbox{$X$}%1
  \fbox{${X}$}%2
  \fbox{$\vphantom{X}$}%3
  \fbox{${\vphantom{X}}$}%4

  \fbox{$X^2$}%5
  \fbox{${X}^2$}%6
  \fbox{$\vphantom{X}^2$}%7
  \fbox{${\vphantom{X}}^2$}%8
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As opposed to `{X}`, which is a letter, the construct `{\vphantom{X}}` is an empty hbox with the width and depth of the letter X.  I guess TeX treats these differently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the same reason

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fbox{${\vphantom{X}}^{\rlap{\vrule height0pt depth0.1pt width 2cm}2}$}%
\fbox{${\kern0ptX}^2$}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

The rule is just to show the height is the same.

Actually the comparison should be with

```
\fbox{${\vphantom{X}}^{\rlap{\vrule height0pt depth0.1pt width 2cm}2}$}%
\fbox{$\hbox{$X$}^2$}
```

that yields the same output.

When TeX has to add a superscript to a box (and a subformula in braces containing more than a single math character counts as a box), it has no clue about what character to append the superscript to, only the box's height.

When you do `\vphantom{X}` in math mode, TeX builds a box with `\setbox0=\hbox{$X$}`, then sets `\wd0=0pt` and does `\box0`. Apart from setting the width, it's the same as doing `\hbox{$X$}`.

Appending a superscript field to a single math character is different, because now TeX knows much more about the object.

Let's examine a simpler case

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\showoutput

$\vphantom{X}^2$

${\vphantom{X}}^2$

\end{document}
```

The relevant bits of the log file are

```
....\mathon
....\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x0.0
....\hbox(4.51111+0.0)x4.48613, shifted -3.62892
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/7 2
....\mathoff
```

and

```
....\mathon
....\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x0.0
.....\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x0.0
....\hbox(4.51111+0.0)x4.48613, shifted -4.36111
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/7 2
....\mathoff
```

If we add `\showlists` before the two closing `$` characters, we get

```
### math mode entered at line 6
\mathchoice
D\mathord
D.\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x0.0
T\mathord
T.\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x0.0
S\mathord
S.\hbox(4.78334+0.0)x0.0
s\mathord
s.\hbox(3.41667+0.0)x0.0
\mathord
^\fam0 2
```

for the first formula and

```
### math mode entered at line 8
\mathord
.\mathchoice
.D\mathord
.D.\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x0.0
.T\mathord
.T.\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x0.0
.S\mathord
.S.\hbox(4.78334+0.0)x0.0
.s\mathord
.s.\hbox(3.41667+0.0)x0.0
^\fam0 2
```

for the second formula. The difference is subtle: in the first case the superscript is appended to an empty `\mathord` atom, in the second case to the whole box.

Comment: I don't see how that explains the difference between `%7` and `%8`. From what you write, `\vphantom{X}` is a box just like `{\vphantom{X}}` is.

Comment: @mhchem I added the analysis for that case too.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to summarize egreg's detailed analysis in my own words.

The effect is a combination of two things.

First, TeX can apply a superscript either to a character or a box. Character: it knows more and can place the superscript at a better position. Box: it knows nothing more than the dimensions of that box "(and a subformula in braces containing more than a single math character counts as a box)". This explains `%5`, `%6`, and `%8`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
  \fbox{$X^2$}%
  \fbox{${X}^2$}%
  \fbox{${XX}^2$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Second, writing a superscript directly after a `\vphantom` somehow is not applied to that `\vphantom`. This explains `%7`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
  \fbox{$\vphantom{\rule{1pt}{30pt}}^2$}
  \fbox{$\vphantom{\rule{1pt}{30pt}}{}^2$}
  \fbox{${\vphantom{\rule{1pt}{30pt}}}^2$}
\end{document}
```

[image]